# $T$ unbounded operator not closed $\implies$ resolvent of T is empty?

Tags: spectral-theory, unbounded-operators

I am studying the subject of unbounded operators  and I'm wondering why if an operator is not closed than his resolvent is empty. Thanks !

Comment: Maybe you need to be careful with definitions.  Suppose I take the identity operator and restrict it to a proper dense subspace.  This operator is not closed; is 0 in its resolvent set?  Some definitions would say that it is, e.g [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolvent_set).

Comment: At the beginning I wonder why in the definition of resolvent  we need to ask that the operator must be closed. I'm reading in the book of Reed and Simon, the definition of resolvent that they give is: if $T$ is **closed** then $\lambda$ is in the resolvent set, if $\lambda I-T$ is a bijection of $D(T)$ with a bounded inverse. Then I search online and I see that the reason we need $T$ closed is to not have empty resolvant, and that's why I'm asking this question... (
sorry for my english, I'm not a native person but I hope it remains understandable)

Comment: Ah, so note the word "bijection". For my example $0I - T$ is not surjective.  So then if $(\lambda I - T)$ is bijective, then $(\lambda I - T)^{-1}$ is an everywhere defined bounded operator.  Hence it is a closed operator, and you can show as an exercise this implies that $\lambda I - T$ is closed too, and hence $T$ itself must be closed as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your definition of "resolvent" apparently says that $\lambda$ is in the resolvent if $\lambda I - T$ is injective **and surjective**, and has a bounded inverse.

We have the following lemma:

> Let $A$ be an unbounded operator with domain $D(A)$ and image $R(A)$.  Suppose $A$ is injective, and consider $A^{-1}$ as an unbounded operator with domain $D(A^{-1}) = R(A)$.  Then $(A, D(A))$ is a closed operator iff $(A^{-1}, D(A^{-1}))$ is.

You can give a very quick proof by looking at the graphs of $A, A^{-1}$ as subsets of $H \oplus H$ and seeing how they relate to one another.

Now in our example, if you want $\lambda$ to be in the resolvent set of $T$ then we need to have $\lambda I - T$ injective and $R(\lambda I - T) = H$.  Moreover the inverse $(\lambda I - T)^{-1}$, whose domain is $H$, is a bounded and everywhere defined operator, so in particular it is a closed operator.  By the lemma, $\lambda I - T$ is closed as well, and this implies $T$ is closed.